# Mybb sceditor extra fields

Tags: php, command, mybb, sceditor

I'm trying add extra content to mybb sceditor using three text area fields but it won't allow me to insert content.

I tried to add a function but cant get it working - help is appreciated!

```
    $.sceditor.command.set('hidep', {
    _dropDown: function (editor, caller) {
        var $content;

        $content = $(
            '<div>' +
            '<div>' +
            '<label for="hidep">' + editor._('Amount of gems') + '</label> ' +
            '<input type="text" id="hidep" />' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div>' +
            '<label for="des">' + editor._('Content') + '</label> ' +
            '<input type="text" id="des" />' +
            '</div>' +
            
            '<div>' +
            '<label for="destitle">' + editor._('Title') + '</label> ' +
            '<input type="text" id="destitle" />' +
            '</div>' +              
            
            '<div><input type="button" class="button" value="' + editor._('Insert') + '" /></div>' +
            '</div>'
        );

        $content.find('.button').on('click', function (e) {
            var val = $content.find('#hidep').val(),
                description = $content.find('#des').val();
                descriptiontitle = $content.find('#destitle').val();
            if (val) {
                // needed for IE to reset the last range
                $(editor).trigger('focus');

                if (!editor.getRangeHelper().selectedHtml() || description) {
                    if (!description)
                        description = val;

                    editor.insert('[hide cost="' + val + '" ' + destitle + ']' + description + '[/hide]');
                } else
                    editor.execCommand('createlink', 'mailto:' + val);
            }

            editor.closeDropDown(true);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        editor.createDropDown(caller, 'inserthidep', $content.get(0));
    },
    exec: function (caller) {
        $.sceditor.command.get('hidep')._dropDown(this, caller);
    }
});
```

And it should look like this!

```
[hide cost="50" title="Good Stuff"]This is hidden content[/hide]
```

Comment: You also need to set the BBCode. That code creates the button which is used to operate. In order to have BBCode, you need to see the section on how to create a BBCode command (it is an included plugin)

Comment: if you mean code function, i have allready plugin, just need in sceditor add button

Comment: Where's the `title="` for the BBCode?